# Angularjs isolate scope fails in undebuggable way

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use isolate scopes with an angular directive.  Here's the HTML.  You can assume I have a valid array in the objectivesJson property:

```html
<div lesson-plan objectives="objectivesJson">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="objective in objectivesCollection" >
      {{ objective.description }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

At first I tried implementing my own 'isolation' via prototype scope & watches. This works, the list renders as expected:

```coffee
  education.student.lessonPlan.directive = (Resource, $timeout) ->
  {
    restrict:   'A'
    scope: true
    controller: [ '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', ( $scope, $elem, $attrs ) ->

      $scope.$watch( $attrs.objectives, ( newValue ) ->
        $scope.objectivesCollection = newValue
      )

    ]
  }
```

But it's a bit of boilerplate, and as far as I understand, I should be able to achieve this with an isolate scope. Here's what I tried:

```
education.student.lessonPlan.directive = (Resource, $timeout) ->
  {
    restrict:   'A'
    scope: { objectivesCollection: '=objectives' }
    controller: [ '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', ( $scope, $elem, $attrs ) ->

    ]
  }
```

But it doesn't work, the UL list is empty in the DOM. There are no errors in the console, so I don't know what is going wrong, and there is nowhere to debug into. Any ideas? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about the 'scope' syntax?

Comment: why are you using `controller` instead of `link`?

Comment: I don't know, why shouldn't I? Examples seem to be pretty split either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be confusing because is something that changed recently.

In 1.0.x (and 1.1.x) the isolated scope was leaking all over the place. So something like that:

```
<div foo bar>{{baz}}</div>
```

If `foo` has an isolated scope, that scope would be accessible inside `bar` and even accessible inside the div itself. That behavior was problematic so it was fixed recently in 1.2.x.

Now, if `foo` has an isolated scope, `bar` scope is still the parent scope (the controller in this case) and the same goes for what's inside the div itself (`{{baz}}` in our case).

So guessing that you're running the last Angular version. Only what's inside of your `lesson-plan` can access your isolated scope. That means that the scope of the `ul` is the controller itself. If you put that `ul` inside the directive's template (via `template` or `templateUrl`) then it will work.

Comment: Ah! Ok. I was thinking that the created isolate scope was accessible  to the directive's element & all child elements contained within it, sort of like an isolated component. But what you're saying is that the isolate scope is super duper isolated, and is only accessible on the actual directive-tagged element itself, and within any templates you happen to render from inside the directive. yeah?

Comment: So, now that isolates dont do what I want anymore(I want to keep my HTML in the DOM, not in a template string/file), that begs the question: whats the best way to achieve the component separation(via attrs) that im going for here? Is it the prototype & watch method as per my example?

Comment: You could create another directive like `lesson-objective` which will require `lesson-plan`. Then `lesson-plan` will have a controller with the objective collection so the new one will have access to it. It is still not the same, some html will be in templates, but well, doing what you have right now with 1.2.x is extremely hacky.

Answer (score 0):

The list is not part of your directive. And since the directive's scope is **isolated** it can only be accessed by the directive.

Comment: thanks, you are right, but i'm giving it to Jesus for all the extra explanation!